# Galaxy Pop Gt-S5570 Is Stuck At Samsung Logo After Installing Cynogenmod 10.1

Tags: cyanogenmod, 4.1-jelly-bean, clockworkmod-recovery, boot, samsung-galaxy-mini

I tried to install Cyanogenmod 10.1 on my galaxy pop gt-s5570 using clockwork recovery 4.0.0.5...

Installation of cynogenmod 10.1 (cm-10.1.0-RC5-GT-S5570-tass) and Gapps successfully completes but after reboot phone is stuck at samsung logo
I tried wipe Data/cache/dalvik cache but still the same problem.. please help me out..

Comment: How long did you wait during Samsung logo? Maybe it takes time..

Comment: I waited for 1hr..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "release candidate" is not a stable release. You should report this error to the Cyanogenmod developers so that it can be investigated and fixed for the final release.

Comment: can You suggest any stable version which can work perfectly on my Phone.. Thank you for your valuable answer..

Comment: I suggest you use the most recent stable version for your device that's listed on the Cyanogenmod website. If there hasn't been a stable release for your device yet, and the release candidate doesn't work for you, you'll have to try a different ROM or re-flash the stock ROM.

Comment: Ok i will check for the stable rom if available.. or else flash a stock rom.. Thanks Once again...

Comment: You don't need to thank me, but if you're satisfied with the answer, *accept* it (with the green tick on the left) so other visitors know your question is answered.

Answer (score 0):

Samnsung Galaxy Pop

http://galaxypophacker.blogspot.com/2013/01/ics-stable-cyanogenmod-101nightly-for.html

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2060605

I am using cm-10.1-20130126-EXPERIMENTAL-tass for 5-6 months

very stable